# Как в Isotope автоматически расположить картинки, не задавая размеры родительского блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую плагин [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), но все равно, это не то, что нужно.
Нужно автоматически расставлять картинки в блоке случайным образом.
Ширина и высота блока должны выбираться исходя из размеров картинок внутри него.

Пробовал еще masonry и Shuffle, но там так же: или высоту нужно задавать, или ширину. Получается, что или колонки одинаковы по ширине, или ряды одинаковы по высоте.

Пример желаемого поведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в Isotope автоматически расположить картинки, не задавая размеры родительского блока?

Comment: Тебе надо посмотреть в сторону masonry grid

Comment: та я смотрел и masonry и isotop и Shuffle, но не подошли.. им нужно или высоту задавать, или ширину указывать

Answer (score 1):

Найти плагин и посмотреть пару примеров можно [здесь](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/).

```js
$(function() {

  var $container = $('#am-container'),
    $imgs = $container.find('img').hide(),
    totalImgs = $imgs.length,
    cnt = 0;

  $imgs.each(function(i) {
    var $img = $(this);
    $('<img/>').load(function() {
      ++cnt;
      if (cnt === totalImgs) {
        $imgs.show();
        $container.montage({
          liquid: false,
          fillLastRow: true
        });

      }
    }).attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
  });
  
});
```

```css
.am-wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.am-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/js/jquery.montage.min.js"></script>

  <div class="am-container" id="am-container">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/1.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/2.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/3.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/4.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/5.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/6.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/7.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/8.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/9.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/10.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/11.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/12.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/13.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/14.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/15.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/16.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/17.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/18.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/19.jpg"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/20.jpg"></img>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: я смотрел этот пример, он не подходит, там высота картинок одинаковая